# Suppose $X_1\cdots X_n$ are correlated normal random variables...

Tags: probability, expectation, covariance, variance

Suppose $X_1\cdots X_n$ are correlated normal random variables... such that $E(X_i) = 0$, $Cov(X_i, X_j ) = ρσ^2$ for $i$ not equal to $j$, and $Var(X_i) = σ^2$.

In the case where $ρ = 0.2, σ^2 = 2$ and $n = 100$, find the covariance matrix of the multivariate Normal distribution for $X = (X_1, . . . , X_n)'$ and hence find the variance of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

All I know is that I apparently need to consider $Y = BX =\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

This is the only hint our lecturer gave us.  But I am still unsure how to go about doing this.

Thank you

Comment: The covariance matrix just has $\sigma^2$ on the diagonal and $\rho\sigma^2$ on the off-diagonals. It's unclear how to answer the question in RStudio without more information. Maybe just doing the matrix multiplications $B\Sigma B'$ you used to compute the variance from the correlation matrix?

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're asking cause you imply that you've found the variance

Answer (score 1):

The covariance matrix $Cov(X)$ has $\sigma^2$ on the diagonals and $\rho\sigma^2$ on the off diagonals.

You can express the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ as $BX$ where $B$ is the column matrix of all ones. Then using the formula for covariance of $BX$ we get
$$
Var(\sum X) = Cov(BX)= B'Cov(X)B.
$$

The question is presumably asking you to make these matrices and do the multiplications in Rstudio.